# Replace http with relative url // on any CSS, JS, HTML, PHP and TPL file on the document root server

Tags: javascript, php, replace, centos6

from command line or PHP, no matter what.

How to replace all the "http://example.com" strings with "//example.com" (relative protocol URL) on **any** CSS, JS, HTML, PHP and TPL file on a CentOS server?
Possible by command line directly?
THANK YOU :-)

Comment: and what if one of the html A tags links to a server w/o https?

Comment: no, example.com is my domain...just my domain ;-) obviously. Thanks

Comment: Like in the files ? 

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/

Comment: this could work? `grep -rl 'http://example.com' ./ | xargs sed -i 's|http://example.com|//example.com|g'` put that ./ is the current main www directory for all i need....and if it works, is a problem if it searches for all files instead of those specific file extensions only?

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) is one option.

Navigate to whatever folder you want to modify the pages in in the file explorer.

Hit `CTRL+H`

In the search box type "http" leave the replace box empty. Repeat with "https".

It will search and I believe it asks to confirm before changing your files. Idr.